# Problem when using React context with localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-context

I'm writing an React webpage which has a theme Context that gets theme (light or dark) from local storage (default to light if local storage value are not set). Here's the code of the context:

```js
// theme-context.tsx
import { createContext, Dispatch, ReactNode, SetStateAction, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export type ThemeOpt = 'light' | 'dark'

export interface ThemeContextInterface {
    theme: ThemeOpt
    setTheme: Dispatch<SetStateAction<ThemeOpt>>
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextInterface | null>(null)

export interface ThemeProviderInterface {
    children: ReactNode[] | ReactNode
}

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: ThemeProviderInterface) => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState<ThemeOpt>('light')
    useEffect(() => {
        const t = localStorage.getItem('theme')
        console.log(t)   // for testing
        if (t === 'light' || t === 'dark') setTheme(t)
    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
    }, [theme])
    return <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
}

export default ThemeProvider
```

Code works, but the problem comes when I set theme to 'dark' and try to reload, the page still loads with 'light' theme. Then I added console.log() line and get this output:

```
dark
light
```

So the local value did change, and then somehow changed again to default value when reload.
What part when wrong in this situation? 
Also I couldn't find any similar problem, so if there are duplicates please link it here, thanks.

Comment: Your're overwriting localStorage theme in the second useEffect on first render.

Comment: @ksav anyway to fix this?

Comment: Instead of the second useeffect you can do the setitem function in a onClick function. So that you can avoid the overwriting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@ksav** mentioned you are overwriting your theme in the second `useEffect`.

Simplifying the flow a bit, a specific fix for your code would be:

```
const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: ThemeProviderInterface) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<ThemeOpt>(localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light'); // directly initialising with local storage or default value

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme) {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
    }
  }, [theme]); // every time the theme state updates we also update in local storage

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**@arp** said something interesting though. You can and **should** update your data in the `onClick` handler as an effect is not necessary here. An effect will cause the local storage to be updated only after the state is set and the component re-renders, which is not needed. More than that, if you changed another state instead of modifying local storage then this would also cause an extra render (see [automatic batching](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-feature-automatic-batching), which would not work with your code as updates are decoupled).

The conclusion is that you don't have to wait for the state to be updated in order to know that you should also update the local storage. You can do both of them at the same time in the `onClick` handler. This increases performance and is the recommended approach.